# How to turn off run selected text in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I want to turn off run selected text in vs code, but I don't know where's this option exactly.

For example in this code:

```
result = "Hello"

print(result)
```

If I accidentally selected the last 4 characters `ult)` by mouse and hit run, the output won't be "Hello", it will produce this error:

```
$ python -u "/home/irkoi/Documents/projects/Javascript/scripts/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
  File "/home/irkoi/Documents/projects/Javascript/scripts/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1
    ult)
       ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

Notice: It creates a file called `tempCodeRunnerFile.py` and runs it, but this is not the file that I want to run.

I guess this may be because of the **code runner** extension, but this is the first time that it behaves this behavior.

**Thanks** for reading this issue, your help will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's weird that I'm answering my question, but I discovered a solution.

My solution was to modify the **settings.json** file property `"code-runner.ignoreSelection"`, it has the value false by default, I set it to true.

**In details:**

- Click on the file menu, then choose preferences.
- Go to settings and in the search bar, search for **JSON**
- Untick the option **Use Split JSON** if it was ticked.
- Click on **Edit in settings.json**.
- put this line `"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true` in your settings.json file (before the last curly brace).

I hope that helps anyone who encounters the same problem that I had.

Comment: FYI, answering your own question isn't that weird. You are providing a reference for others who might have the same question. Good job, you! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question